# Implement Server-side Value Change Events/Listeners

Tags: java, xpages

I am trying to implement listeners to track values. I was looking at Tony McGuckin's xSnippet http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=server-side-value-change-events-listeners but it is failing. When I paste the code it fails on the page. It looks like there is an issue with the java code, but I am guessing here. Everything below the "Pizza" comment is commented out and I am not java smart enough to fix it.

```
package com.ibm.xsp.beans;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
 import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;

/*
 * @author Tony McGuckin, IBM
 */
public class ChangeRequestBean { 

  public ChangeRequestBean (){}

  public void valueChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent){

// Note: valueChangeListener's are fired during the PROCESS_VALIDATIONS phase
// but only after any binded validator(s) on the component succeeds...
UIComponent c = valueChangeEvent.getComponent();
System.out.println("Value changed component: " + c.getId());
System.out.println("Old value: " + valueChangeEvent.getOldValue());
System.out.println("New value: " + valueChangeEvent.getNewValue());

// do something useful...
//    perform second level check with a service...
//    order a pizza using REST... whatever!
/*
if(ChangeRequestService.doesNotApproveThisNewlyValidatedValue(c.getId(), valueChangeEvent.getNewValue()){
  FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  context.addMessage(
    c.getClientId(context), new FacesMessage(
      FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
      ChangeRequestService.getMessage(),
      ChangeRequestService.changeRequest.getSummary()
    )
  );
  // failover to the RENDER_RESPONSE phase...
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
}
    */
   }

} // end ChangeRequestBean
```

If anyone has a field tracking mechanism they would be willing to share that would solve my problem. All the code blog posts on this are a couple years old and I am having some trouble implementing.

[EDIT]

I am running Domino 9.0.1 fp3 if that makes a difference.

Comment: What does the stack trace say about the error?

Comment: The stack trace is blank with the error listed as "variable"

Answer (score 1):

The code in comments is not really working code. It's just there for getting an idea what could be done there.

`ChangeRequestService` stays for a fictive Java class which checks new values with a method doesNotApproveThisNewlyValidatedValue and delivers an error message string.

Just for demonstration purposes this class could look like this:

```
package com.ibm.xsp.beans;

public class ChangeRequestService {

    public static boolean doesNotApproveThisNewlyValidatedValue(String id, Object newValue) {
        if (newValue != null && newValue.toString().length() == 3) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static String getMessage() {
        return "Value can't be 3 characters long ... bla ... bla ...";
    }

}
```

and the code below "pizza" could be

```
    if (ChangeRequestService.doesNotApproveThisNewlyValidatedValue(c.getId(), valueChangeEvent.getNewValue())) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(c.getClientId(context), new FacesMessage(ChangeRequestService.getMessage()));
        // failover to the RENDER_RESPONSE phase...
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
    }
```

It shows the message "Value can't be 3 characters long ... bla ... bla ..." whenever the submitted value is exactly 3 chars long.

I know that's not what you are looking for.

There are some blogs which use Tony's code as a starting point for field tracking like:

- [Using a valueChangeListener to build an Audit Trail](http://www.qtzar.com/using-a-valuechangelistener-to-build-an-audit-trail/)
- [XPages: Detecting and Logging Field Value Changes](http://dmcnally.blogspot.de/2013/02/xpages-detecting-and-logging-field.html)

Look there for ideas and code and implement your own field tracking.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have looked at those blogs and haven't been able to piece together a solution. Thanks for the information on the code!